# Reorganizing an MxN 2D array of datapoints into an N-dimensional array

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

I've got a series of measurements in a 2D array such as

```
T    mu1  mu2  mu3  a    b    c    d    e
0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
0.0  0.0  0.0  2.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
0.0  0.0  0.0  3.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
0.0  0.0  1.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
0.0  0.0  1.0  2.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
0.0  0.0  1.0  3.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
0.0  1.0  2.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
0.0  1.0  2.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
0.0  1.0  2.0  2.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
0.0  1.0  2.0  3.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
0.0  1.0  3.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
0.0  1.0  3.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
0.0  1.0  3.0  2.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
0.0  1.0  3.0  3.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
1.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
1.0  0.0  0.0  2.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
1.0  0.0  0.0  3.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
1.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
1.0  0.0  1.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
1.0  0.0  1.0  2.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
1.0  0.0  1.0  3.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
1.0  1.0  2.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
1.0  1.0  2.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
1.0  1.0  2.0  2.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
1.0  1.0  2.0  3.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
1.0  1.0  3.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
1.0  1.0  3.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
1.0  1.0  3.0  2.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
1.0  1.0  3.0  3.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
```

where `T`, `mu1`, `mu2` and `mu3` are the 4 axes of the variables I control (independent variables). `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` and `e` are the measurements I've made (dependent variables).

I would like to convert this 2D array into a 5D array in numpy. By  specifying `T`, `mu1`, `mu2` and `mu3` (or at least their 4 indexes) I want to be able to retrieve the corresponding `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` and `e` values.

Is there a straightforward way to reshape this kind of array by specifying what columns the axes correspond to? The `MultiIndex` in Pandas seemed to smartly organize it in a table, but seems ill-suited for high dimensional arrays. I won't necessarily know ahead of time what the shape of the ndarray should be, but it seems to me that based on the values it should be possible to reshape the array properly. The increment values for each axis might also be different, but they will always be uniform.

My current idea involves ignoring the `mu1`, `mu2` and `mu3` columns, and stacking sets of `T` data into a 3D array. From there I would stack sets of 3D `mu1` data into a 4D array, and repeat the process with `mu2` and `mu3`. This seems like a tedious process that should have a simple solution though.

Comment: An `ndarray` is indexed with integers 0-n. Are your independent variables constrained this way? Your example data is (with the exception of them being floats instead of integers), but what about your actual data?

Comment: In my actual data, every column will be filled with (ugly) float values. Ideally I'd be able to access measurements by specifying these float values, but it shouldn't be a problem to access data through integer indexes provided it's organized and sorted in a sensible manner

Comment: An N-dimensional array container would only make sense if your points are positioned in a regular lattice, such that there is a single value for every combination of indices in `data[i, j, k, l, m]`. If that's not the case then you would have to decide how to deal with duplicates and/or missing values. Making `i`, `j`, `k`, `l` and `m` arbitrary float values introduces lots of other problems. For example, slice indexing would no longer make sense. What should `data[1.0:2.0]` return, given that there are an infinite number of non-integer values between 1.0 and 2.0?

Comment: Could you explain what you want to actually do with the ND array? It might make more sense to use some form of interpolation.

Comment: Yes, my N-dimensional array would be a regular N-dimensional mesh. The data is a result of various Monte Carlo runs at different temperatures and chemical potentials. The values of the temperature and chemical potentials change in regular intervals, and each combination of temperature and chemical potentials results in a set of measurements (e.g. formation energy, etc.). What I ultimately need is to be able to integrate measurements (using trapezoid rule or similar) along an arbitrary axis, keeping the others constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's make some fake data:

```
# an N x 5 array containing a regular mesh representing the stimulus params
stim_params = np.mgrid[:2, :3, :4, :5, :6].reshape(5, -1).T

# an N x 3 array representing the output values for each simulation run
output_vals = np.arange(720 * 3).reshape(720, 3)

# shuffle the rows for a bit of added realism
shuf = np.random.permutation(stim_params.shape[0])
stim_params = stim_params[shuf]
output_vals = output_vals[shuf]
```

Now you can use [`np.lexsort`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.lexsort.html) to get the set of indices that will sort the rows of your 2D array of simulation parameters such that the values in each column are in ascending order. Having done that, you can apply these indices to the rows of simulation output values.

```
# get the number of unique values for each stimulus parameter
params_shape = tuple(np.unique(col).shape[0] for col in stim_params.T)

# get the set of row indices that will sort the stimulus parameters in ascending
# order, starting with the final column
idx = np.lexsort(stim_params[:, ::-1].T)

# sort and reshape the stimulus parameters:
sorted_params = stim_params[idx].T.reshape((5,) + params_shape)

# sort and reshape the output values
sorted_output = output_vals[idx].T.reshape((3,) + params_shape)
```

I find that the hardest part is often just trying to wrap your head around what all the different dimensions of the outputs correspond to:

```
# array of stimulus parameters, with dimensions (n_params, p1, p2, p3, p4, p5)
print(sorted_params.shape)
# (5, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)

# to check that the sorting worked as expected, we can look at the values of the 
# 5th parameter when all the others are held constant at 0:
print(sorted_params[4, 0, 0, 0, 0, :])
# [0 1 2 3 4 5]

# ... and the 1st parameter when we hold all the others constant:
print(sorted_params[0, :, 0, 0, 0, 0])
# [0, 1]

# ... now let the 1st and 2nd parameters covary:
print(sorted_params[:2, :, :, 0, 0, 0])
# [[[0 0 0]
#   [1 1 1]]

#  [[0 1 2]
#   [0 1 2]]]
```

Hopefully you get the idea. The same indexing logic applies to the sorted simulation outputs:

```
# array of outputs, with dimensions (n_outputs, p1, p2, p3, p4, p5)
print(sorted_output.shape)
# (3, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)

# the first output variable whilst holding the first 4 simulation parameters
# constant at 0:
print(sorted_output[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, :])
# [ 0  3  6  9 12 15]
```