# How to calculate the diameter of irregular shape from jpg input image in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing

I would like to calculate the diameter of an irregular shape, in a given input image like [this sample](http://www.graphic-design-employment.com/images/create-a-simple-shape.jpg). I'm using [this algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38598690/how-to-find-the-diameter-of-objects-using-image-processing-in-python/38616904).

I can’t import a real image, can you help me?
I'm new on stackoverflow..

Comment: Huh? The diameter is the distance across a shape and that distance varies according to where you measure it, so what do you actually want to measure please? Maybe you could add a second, marked up image?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the scipy.ndimage.imread function to import your image into an ndarray and then use the algorithm you mentioned.

```
img = scipy.ndimage.imread("PATH_TO_MY_IMG.jpg")
```

Comment: there is an error      r, c = np.vstack(ndimage.center_of_mass(img, labels, np.arange(nlabels) + 1)).T
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)